# No sé reproduce mi video en HTML5

Tags: html

en mi pagina web mi video aparece pero no se reproduce.¿alguna ayuda?

Pd. Soy novato en esto

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS and Java/mecanica.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
      <source src="../IMG/Half flip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola @donra1212, ¿podrías proporcionar la ruta completa del vídeo?, porque en el código que has compartido en esta publicación la ruta hacia el vídeo no existe.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el OP ha respondido que el problema se debía a que la ruta al archivo era incorrecta.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente era que tenía la ubicación mal escrita nada más.

```
src="../Rocket League Web/IMG/Half flip.mp4"
```

Comment: Igualmente te respondí agregando otras informaciones que pueden resultarte útiles al respecto. Un saludo.

Comment: te recomiendo eliminar la pregunta es un error de sintaxis de la ruta..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer `<video controls autoplay>` en lugar de `autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"`. También es recomendable que uses `<video autoplay muted>` ya que algunos browsers no permiten el autoplay en videos con sonido. Por otra parte en dispositivos móviles el autoplay no se puede hacer.

También existe la opción loop que sustituye autoplay y sirve para que el video inicie automáticamente y se repita al terminar y se utiliza de la misma manera `<video loop muted>`

Si te interesa que el video no llegue a cargarse en los dispositivos móviles debido a que en estos no es practicable el autoplay o para que el usuario decida si desea cargarlo o no, puedes usar este [tool](https://codepen.io/montes_dev/pen/VwebrzX) que he implementado, se trata de un pequeño archivo js.